# What does sig value 0.000 mean?

Tags: anova, descriptive-statistics

May someone advise how a significant value of 0.000 be interpreted in a one way within subject ANOVA test, with one independent var, comprising of 2 levels.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A $p$-value can't actually reach 0, in most cases, so this just means that you obtained $p < .001$ and your software rounded it to 0.000.

Comment: Thank you for the kind clarification. Do we need to check the Levene's test output to determine if the p is really less than the alpha level?

Comment: @user39531 That depends. What's the alpha level?

Comment: I set alpha level to be 0.05

Comment: @user39531 We know that $p < .001$, as I said above, and $.001 < .05$, so $p < .05$.